# Add username input to python chat program

Tags: python, sockets, chat

So I found this chat program on http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_tcp_server_client_chat_server_chat_client_select.php 
And I want to use this at my school for me and my friends, put I don't want to chat to be ex: [192.168.1.3] "Message". I want to be able to add another argument so it shows there name they input instead of Ip. It would be a little hard to have everyone using ips. Any suggestions?

Server Code:

```
# chat_server.py

import sys
import socket
import select

HOST = '' 
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 
PORT = 9009

def chat_server():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    # add server socket object to the list of readable connections
    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)

    print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

    while 1:

        # get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        # 4th arg, time_out  = 0 : poll and never block
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)

        for sock in ready_to_read:
            # a new connection request recieved
            if sock == server_socket: 
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr

                broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered our chatting room\n" % addr)

            # a message from a client, not a new connection
            else:
                # process data recieved from client, 
                try:
                    # receiving data from the socket.
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:
                        # there is something in the socket
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '] ' + data)  
                    else:
                        # remove the socket that's broken    
                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)

                        # at this stage, no data means probably the connection has been broken
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr) 

                # exception 
                except:
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()

# broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast (server_socket, sock, message):
    for socket in SOCKET_LIST:
        # send the message only to peer
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection
                socket.close()
                # broken socket, remove it
                if socket in SOCKET_LIST:
                    SOCKET_LIST.remove(socket)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_server())
```

Client Code:

```
# chat_client.py

import sys
import socket
import select

def chat_client():
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
        print 'Usage : python chat_client.py hostname port'
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages'
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in ready_to_read:             
            if sock == s:
                # incoming message from remote server, s
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()     

            else :
                # user entered a message
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_client())
```

Comment: This could be done in the client code that when the client starts it asks the user to enter an username and when the client connects to the server it can send an username. Of course on the server side you have to capture this and use it for your purpose.

Comment: Following what @ρss suggested: after connecting to the server do `s.send(pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name)` to send it the username (if you do not want to ask the user explicitly). On the other end, make the server read that and save it along with the socket/ip. If you aren't on unix, use `getpass.getuser()` instead

Comment: Hey Pynchia I am running Mac OSX (so I am using Unix) And can you show me how to input this into the code? I am new to Python (just learning)?

Comment: I figured this out, and I imported time so I could add a tenth of a second delay when it sends data so it isn't all screwy. Thank you to all that helped